# removing adjacent newline characters sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to remove newline characters when the next character is also a newline 
 using the Function I wrote below, and im running into a problem. When I input this string :

```
"Line1
 Line2

 Line3 



 Line4"
```

It removes the newlines after line 1 and 2 , but the lines between 3 and 4 remain ? Any ideas as to why the function doesn't work then ?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS removeLines;
CREATE FUNCTION test_dev.removeLines(address varchar(255)) 
RETURNS varchar(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE i int;
SET i = 0;
WHILE i < length(address)-1 DO
      IF(((SUBSTR(address,i,1) in (CHAR(10) ,CHAR(13))) AND (SUBSTR(address,i+1,1) in (CHAR(10) ,CHAR(13)))   ) )                                                               
      THEN set  address = INSERT(address,i,1,'');
            SET i= i+1;
      ELSE set i= i+1;
      END IF;
END WHILE;
RETURN address;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why not use the replace() function instead of writing your own?

Comment: For the address formatting I need to leave one newline each time several are found, as I understand it Replace() would remove all of them ?

Comment: Jamie McManus, see my answer below on how to remove several instances of the repeating string but leave only one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you increment `i` after you replace a newline. Consider the following simple string:

```
1\n\n\n2
01 2 3 4 -- indexes
```

When `i` is `1`, you see that there are newlines at indexes `i=1` and `i+1=2`, so you remove the first one with `INSERT()`. Now the string is:

```
1\n\n2
01 2 3
```

and you do `SET i = i + 1`. Now `i` is 2, but indexes `i=2` and `i+1=3` don't have newlines, so you don't remove the next newline.

Change it so that you only increment `i` when you don't find a pair of newlines.

```
  IF(((SUBSTR(address,i,1) in (CHAR(10) ,CHAR(13))) AND (SUBSTR(address,i+1,1) in (CHAR(10) ,CHAR(13)))   ) )                                                               
  THEN set  address = INSERT(address,i,1,'');
  ELSE set i= i+1;
  END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way to write your function so you don't have to manually keep track of character indexing.

```
while instr(address, '\r\n\r\n') do
   address = replace(address, '\r\n\r\n', '\r\n');
end while;
```

I didn't have a chance to test this in a database so the syntax may not be 100% correct.